# Python - make a dictionary from a csv file with multiple categories

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, python-3.x

I am trying to make a dictionary from a csv file in python, but I have multiple categories. I want the keys to be the ID numbers, and the values to be the name of the items. Here is the text file:

```
"ID#","name","quantity","price"
"1","hello kitty","4","9999"
"2","rilakkuma","3","999"
"3","keroppi","5","1000"
"4","korilakkuma","6","699"
```

and this is what I have so far:

```
txt = open("hk.txt","rU")

file_data = txt.read()
lst = []           #first make a list, and then convert it into a dictionary.
for key in file_data:
        k = key.split(",")
        lst.append((k[0],k[1]))

dic = dict(lst)
print(dic)
```

This just prints an empty list though. I want the keys to be the ID#, and then the values will be the names of the products. I will make another dictionary with the names as the keys and the ID#'s as the values, but I think it will be the same thing but the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary directly:

```
dictionary = {}
file_data.readline()   # skip the first line         
for key in file_data:
    key = key.replace('"', '').strip()
    k = key.split(",")
    dictionary[k[0]] = k[1]
```

Comment: I tried it this way and this is just fine. :) However, the result is printed as such:  `{'"3"': '"keroppi"', '"4"': '"korilakkuma"', '"1"': '"hello kitty"', '"2"': '"rilakkuma"', '"ID#"': '"name"'}`

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this site so I'm not very good at formatting.

Comment: I mean the edit for my answer.  I added the line `key = key.replace('"', '').strip()`.  This shoudl remove the double quotes that you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to handle your data; it'll remove the quoting and handle the splitting:

```
results = {}

with open('hk.txt', 'r', newline='') as txt:
    reader = csv.reader(txt)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the header line
    for row in reader:
        results[row[0]] = row[1]
```

For your sample input, this produces:

```
{'4': 'korilakkuma', '1': 'hello kitty', '3': 'keroppi', '2': 'rilakkuma'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [csv DictReader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

```
import csv

result={}
with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    for d in csv.DictReader(f):
        result[d['ID#']]=d['name']

print(result)
# {'1': 'hello kitty', '3': 'keroppi', '2': 'rilakkuma', '4': 'korilakkuma'}
```

Comment: Note that the OP is using Python 3, so the `newline=''` parameter is recommended.

Comment: I'll fix that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this or use any library to read the file.

```
txt = open("hk.txt","rU")

file_data = txt.read()
file_lines = file_data.split("\n")
lst = []           #first make a list, and then convert it into a dictionary.
for linenumber in range(1,len(file_lines)):
        k = file_lines[linenumber].split(",")
        lst.append((k[0][1:len(k[0])-1],k[1][1:len(k[1])-1]))

dic = dict(lst)
print(dic)
```

but you can use the dict directly as well.